# empty Android resource xml files being generated

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I modify any of my resource xml files (layout, menu, values) I get:
`Error in an XML file: aborting build.` 
When I delete the (empty) ....out.xml file, restart Eclipse and run the file again, all is well!
Eclipse Indigo, Android SDK  on W7.

Comment: Did you try Project | Clean then do a rebuild?

Comment: Don't run your application in your xml files, it'll just create empty out.xml files

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's a quirk of Eclipse. I have found that the problem only occurs if, after saving the xml (say, manifest or resource layout) I go straight into a build. If I close the xml in Eclipse first, the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you try to run an xml file. You can't run android xml files. Find out how Eclipse is trying to run your xml files.